# Does "duct open to the wall of the room" make sense?

Tags: adjectives

Consider:

> The outside air is introduced into the house through the duct that connects the inside and outside of the house.

I rewrote this more specifically as follows:

> The duct **is open/exposed to** the inside and outside walls of the
>   house.

I would like to know which of "open" and "exposed" makes sense or is better.

Comment: I think it's *slightly* odd to talk about something like a duct "opening" to both sides of the wall it passes through. I'd normally think of the duct as being "present" in the room, and "opening" wherever it does on the outside wall. But personally I'd use the verb form *(The duct **opens** to the outside wall)* rather than adjectival *(**is open** to...).* And I'd say that although you might get away with "exposed", it seems to suggest that in other circumstances it might *not* reach open air and be exposed - which is pretty meaningless for a duct.

Comment: Outside of "architect jargon" contexts, it might be more natural to say something like *The inside duct [vent] **leads** [through] **to** the outside wall.*

Comment: Is there anything particular about the first sentence that you think is wrong. Why did you want to rewrite it?

Comment: suggested change: Outside air comes into the house through the duct from the outside.There is  no need to repeat house here. This really sounds like translation to me, which is why I simplified it. Like I often do for sentences in other languages, which I translate into English.

Comment: Actually: Outside air comes into the house through the duct. Even shorter. In any event, Rama9's  sentence is unwieldy.

Comment: I want to use the word "wall". Does "The duct (openings) open to the inside and outside walls" make sense?

Comment: No, it does not. And it's far from your original idea. The air comes into the house through ducts in the WALL. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

An air duct brings outside air into the house or carries inside air out.  It is a given that there will be a duct opening on the exterior wall (or roof) and a duct opening on an interior wall (or ceiling).

If you want to find a verb for this opening of the duct, that verb would be **opens**, complemented by a prepositional phrase introduced by **to**:

One end of the duct **opens to** the outside and the other end of the duct **opens to** an interior space.

Here are [some examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22duct%20opens%20to%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

Comment: I want to focus attention on "wall" not "space".  According to your advice, it is possible to use the expression " duct has an opening on a wall ".  Is it possible to use the expression "duct opens to a wall"?

Comment: No, it cannot open to a wall. It must open to an open area, either to another duct or to an open space. For example, the duct opens to **the outside** (not to the outer wall). If you want to focus on the wall, don't use the verb, but the noun: *The **opening** of the duct is on the outer wall.*  The duct opens to the exterior|interior.

Answer (score 1):

The outside air is introduced into the house through the duct that connects the inside and outside of the house.=

**Outside air comes into the house through a duct**.

Meaning-wise, no more is needed. That is how technical English would express this.